# PhantomJS or CasperJS open page and execute bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs, bookmarklet

Is it possible to open a web page with PhantomJS or CasperJS and then run a bookmarklet on that page?

I would like to get the DOM of this result to check if the bookmarklet was loaded correctly.

I've already searched on the web and tried many things but found no solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, I do not believe that PhantomJS or CasperJS uses the [`javascript:`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa767736(v%3Dvs.85)) protocol that bookmarklets use.

Alternatively, you can use [`casper.evaluate()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate) to execute the bookmarklet contents in the webpage:

```
casper.evaluate(function () {
  // Insert your bookmarklet code here
});
```

You can get the DOM of the resulting webpage afterwards with [`casper.getHTML()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#gethtml).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this seems not to work. I tried page.evaluateJavaScript but I get the following error: Error Code: 301 Protocol "javascript" is unkown. Is there another way to test my bookmarklet?

Comment: As an alternative you can use the free 'iMacros for Chrome' extension to test your bookmarklet in the preferred way. (Of course, if you are open to install such an add-on and run this browser.)

Comment: @MisterPhantom Remove the `javascript:` portion of the bookmarklet before placing it in the function.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The protocol error is solved by removing `javascript:`. But it looks like the code in my external js file is not beeing executed. The file has a function where a new script element is created. this script element has an onload attribute, which should invoke javascript code from another js file which is located on an external server. PhantomJS gives me an TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating xxxfunctionName) Trace: in function "onload".

Comment: It looks like I've managed to load the local javascript file. But PhantomJS seems not to support ES6, which is used by the javascript file on the server. So now I am looking how to use babel to fix this problem.